# Sysvinit alternative of systemd-analyze and systemctl?

Tags: startup, alternative, systemd, optimization

I am trying to tweak my system's start time. Usually I go about it by using

```
systemd-analyze blame
```

Which gives me a list of stuff and how long it takes them to start. For this machine I don't need most of them, so it's a case of then

```
systemctl mask SERVICENAME
```

Or

```
systemctl disable SERVICENAME
```

But I am on a sysvinit system no and seeking alternatives for those commands.

Comment: Ubuntu Linux has had upstart since version 6.  What version of Ubuntu Linux are you now using that is still a System 5 `init` system?  If you aren't asking about Ubuntu then you are on the wrong WWW site.  If you are asking about Ubuntu, then you are almost certainly asking about the wrong toolset.

Answer (score 3):

## Systemd commands    and    Sysvinit commands

```
Systemd Command  ------------------------------- Sysvinit Command
systemctl start fooserv ------------------------ service fooserv start 
systemctl stop fooserv ------------------------- service fooserv stop 
systemctl restart fooserv ---------------------- service fooserv restart 
systemctl reload fooserv ----------------------- service fooserv reload 
systemctl condrestart fooserv ------------------ service fooserv condrestart 
systemctl status fooserv ----------------------- service fooserv status 
systemctl list-unit-files --type=service ------- ls /etc/rc.d/init.d/ 
systemctl enable fooserv ----------------------- chkconfig fooserv on 
systemctl disable fooserv ---------------------- chkconfig fooserv off 
systemctl is-enabled fooserv ------------------- chkconfig fooserv 
systemctl list-unit-files --type=service ------- chkconfig --list 
ls /etc/systemd/system/*.wants/fooserv.service - chkconfig fooserv --list 
systemctl daemon-reload ------------------------ chkconfig fooserv --add 
systemctl isolate multi-user.target ------------ telinit 3 
systemctl halt --------------------------------- halt
systemctl poweroff ----------------------------- poweroff
systemctl reboot ------------------------------- reboot
systemctl suspend ------------------------------ pm-suspend
systemctl hibernate ---------------------------- pm-hibernate
journalctl -f ---------------------------------- tail -f /var/log/messages
```

`systemd-analyze` is a new command to check boot time

`systemctl mask` is a stronger version of `systemctl disable`. This will link these units to /dev/null, making it impossible to start them.

## [Source](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Systemd)